# New multipage environment with different background pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

I try to create multipage environment for output list of components. This list may be located in any part of the document (in the middle for example). I can create such list environment which work like this:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{elementlist}{%
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \linespread{1.34}\selectfont
  \enlargethispage{-3\baselineskip}
  \begin{longtable}[|c|]{@{}p{19mm}@{\hspace{2mm}}p{108mm}@{\hspace{2mm}}p{8mm}@{\hspace{2mm}}p{43mm}@{\hspace{1mm}}@{}}%
  }{%
  \end{longtable}%
  \ClearShipoutPicture
  \newpage 
 }%

\begin{document}
 \lipsum[3-6]
 \begin{elementlist}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \end{elementlist}
\lipsum[7-16]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I need a background frames on all environment pages. But first background frame have to be different from other page background farmes. Background frames I create as fllow:

```
\def\FormFirst{
\pagestyle{empty}
\ClearShipoutPicture
{\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw[black, line  width=0.5mm] ( 2.0, 0.5) rectangle (20.5, 29.2);
\draw[black, line  width=0.5mm] ( 2.0, 0.5) rectangle (20.5, 4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}}}

\def\FormPosterior{
\pagestyle{empty}
\ClearShipoutPicture
{\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw[black, line  width=0.5mm] ( 2.0, 0.5) rectangle (20.5, 29.2);
\draw[black, line  width=0.5mm] ( 2.0, 0.5) rectangle (20.5, 2.0);
\end{tikzpicture}}}}
```

And I know how place `\FormFirst` on first environment page:

```
\newenvironment{elementlist}{%
\FormFirst
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \linespread{1.34}\selectfont
  \enlargethispage{-3\baselineskip}
  \begin{longtable}[|c|]{@{}p{19mm}@{\hspace{2mm}}p{108mm}@{\hspace{2mm}}p{8mm}@{\hspace{2mm}}p{43mm}@{\hspace{1mm}}@{}}%
  }{%
  \end{longtable}%
  \ClearShipoutPicture
  \newpage 
  }%
```

But how place `\FormPosterior` on posterior environment list pages?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Note that you should use `\clearpage`: If you happen to be already on a new page, nothing happens, whereas `\newpage` will start a new page in any case. See the comments in the code for explanations.

```
\newif\ifFirstBackground % Flag to signal whether it's the first page
\newenvironment{elementlist}%
  {\clearpage
   \pagestyle{empty}%
   \ClearShipoutPicture % Just in case there are any leftovers; not really needed
   \FirstBackgroundtrue
   \AddToShipoutPicture{\Background}%
   %%% begin code for foreground
  }%
  {%%% end code for foreground
   \clearpage
   \ClearShipoutPicture % set everything back to normal
   \pagestyle{plain}%
  }

\newcommand\Background % choose an appropriate background depending on flag "FirstBackground"
  {\ifFirstBackground
     \BackgroundPicture{4.5}%
     \global\FirstBackgroundfalse
   \else
     \BackgroundPicture{2.0}%
   \fi
  }

\newcommand\BackgroundPicture[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
   \draw[black, line  width=0.5mm] ( 2.0, 0.5) rectangle (20.5, 29.2);
   \draw[black, line  width=0.5mm] ( 2.0, 0.5) rectangle (20.5, #1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```

[image] [image] [image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newif\ifFirstBackground
\newenvironment{elementlist}%
  {\clearpage
   \pagestyle{empty}%
   \ClearShipoutPicture % Just in case there are any leftovers
   \FirstBackgroundtrue
   \AddToShipoutPicture{\Background}%
   \linespread{1.34}\selectfont
   \enlargethispage{-3\baselineskip}%
   \begin{longtable}[c] {@{}p{19mm}@{\hspace{2mm}}p{108mm}@{\hspace{2mm}}p{8mm}@     {\hspace{2mm}}p{43mm}@{\hspace{1mm}}@{}}%
  }%
  {\end{longtable}%
   \clearpage
   \ClearShipoutPicture
   \pagestyle{plain}%
  }

\newcommand\Background
  {\ifFirstBackground
     \BackgroundPicture{4.5}%
     \global\FirstBackgroundfalse
   \else
     \BackgroundPicture{2.0}%
   \fi
  }

\newcommand\BackgroundPicture[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
   \draw[black, line  width=0.5mm] ( 2.0, 0.5) rectangle (20.5, 29.2);
   \draw[black, line  width=0.5mm] ( 2.0, 0.5) rectangle (20.5, #1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\newcommand{\lline}[4]{%
  \makebox[19mm]{#1} & %
  #2 & %
  \makebox[8mm]{#3} & %
  #4 %
  \tabularnewline}%

\newcommand{\element}[4]{%
  \lline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%

\newcommand{\Part}[1]{%
  \lline{}{\hfill \raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]{#1} \hfill}{}{}}%

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
 \begin{elementlist}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
 \element{C15}{X7R~0805~0,47~uF}{1}{Phillips}
\end{elementlist}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thaks for the answer. But I want use new environment not only at begin of document. If I use this environment after `some text \newpage` result will be predictable. Title background appears under the some text, but I need backgrounds only for environment.

Comment: @Konstantin First, I don't yet understand what you really want to achieve. Can you post the non-working code (containing also `\FormPosterior`; currently your code doesn't use it) and explain what it is supposed to do? Second, the problem with putting commands like your `\FormFirst` and `\FormPosterior` anywhere into other macros is that it is difficult to keep control over the order in which these statements are executed: It may happen that part of the second page has been already processed before the first page is shipped out.

Comment: How can I post code and expectation example? Should i edit my first post?

Comment: I have changed first post. Try to make problem clearly.

Comment: @Konstantin I've modified the answer.